# Binding to a property not specified in the interface bound

Tags: wpf, binding, types, interface

The title is a bit blur here, I didn't find a way to say it more clearly.

Let's take a simple and very clear example of my situation:

**First: I have a custom control, `FooControl` , with a `DependencyProperty` of type `IFoo`. The control is supposed to display `IFoo` objects in a `DataGrid`**

Please note that, of course, the real object is not just about displaying some values, I could have used just a DataGrid for this matter ;)

```
public class FooControl : DataGrid
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Foo!
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FooProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Foo",
                                        typeof(IFoo),
                                        typeof(FooControl),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(FooChanged));
```

**Second: I have an `IFoo` interface**

```
public interface IFoo
{
    IList<double> Values { get; set; }
}
```

**Third: I have a `Foo` object, implementing `IFoo`**

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public IList<double> Values { get; set; }
}
```

**And now, I want an `ObservableFoo`, for binding updates purpose, here it is:**

```
public class ObservableFoo : Foo, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<double> ObservableValues {get; set; }
}
```

Now, THE PROBLEM:

I usually have my `FooControl`s bound to objects of type `Foo`, which are "strict" implementations of the `IFoo` interface.
Now, I also need to have three `FooControl`s which should be bound to objects of type `ObservableFoo` (which obviously are `IFoo`, but also add a property not specified in the interface, ie `ObservableValues` )

in the `FooControl` class, I manually set a binding to the values to be displayed:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the binding on foo values
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyPath">Binding path</param>
    public void SetValuesBinding(string propertyPath)
    {
        // Binding for foovalues
        Binding fooBinding = new Binding(propertyPath);
        fooBinding.Converter = new FooConverter();
        fooBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        fooBinding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.Self);
        fooBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

        this.SetBinding(FooControl.ItemsSourceProperty, fooBinding);
    }
```

When `propertyPath` is `Foo.Values` , it works fine, updating the binding's target will call the `PropertyChangedHandler` I defined for `ItemsSource`

When `propertyPath` is `Foo.ObservableValues`, updating the binding won't call the `PropertyChangedHandler` I defined. However, there is no Binding error displayed on the output window!

In my comprehension of the problem, it means that:

- The Binding "worked", ie. it has found the source property
- BUT, since `ObservableValues` is not in `IFoo` but only in `ObservableFoo`, the binding tries to find `IFoo.ObservableValues` and... cannot update it.

How could I manage to update the binding to `ObservableValues` ?

I hope I made it clear enough for you guys. Please feel free to ask any question if you need me to clarify

Comment: I would recommend getting something like Snoop and verifying that your `ItemsSource` is getting bound correctly to `ObservableValues`. Snoop's website is http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Have you tried: public class ObservableFoo : Foo, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    new public ObservableCollection<double> Values {get; set; }
}?
Notice the **new**.

Comment: @Rachel already done, snoops shows me that there is no value bound, which conforts me in my "no type resolved" hypothesis.

Comment: @jberger done as well, new does not override a property but just hides it. Moreover, my ObservableFoo object also have values :-)

Comment: @Damascus: when the binding is set using `IFoo`, does it bind to the hidden `IList<double> Values` or the `ObservableCollection<double> Values`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally went for a workaround.

I Added a property to the `FooControl` :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The values displayed
    /// </summary>
    public System.Collections.IEnumerable ValuesToDisplay
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Foo is ObservableFoo)
            {
                return (this.Foo as ObservableFoo).ObservableValues;
            }
            else if (this.Foo == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return this.Foo.Values;
            }
        }
    }
```

And I bind the embedded Datagrid's `ItemSource` to this property (using a `RelativeSource` pointing to itself) and... It works fine.

But still, this made me learn something: binding does not resolve types at runtime, it will just take the specified type apparently!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with your binding.

You're binding to RelativeSource Self, which means your binding is reading `FooControl.Foo.ObservableValues`, and since `Foo` is defined as an `IFoo`, the `ObservableValues` property doesn't exist.

A possible alternative would be to set `FooControl.DataContext` equal to `Foo`, and then make your binding simply `ObservableValues` so it is simply calling `DataContext.ObservableValues` instead of `FooControl.Foo.ObservableValues`

If that doesn't work, try putting the `ObservableValues` property on `IFoo`, or make the `Values` property a type which can be inherited by either `IList` or `ObservableCollection` such as `Object`

Comment: Your idea seems fine, unfortunately it doesn't match with the full project architecture (ie. changing `DataContext`, adding something in `IFoo` :-/ I'll post the workaround I made which works fine without altering the software architecture. Working in a big scale application sucks sometimes :-(

Answer (score 0):

mmm... i don't get why you don't have ObservableFoo Implementing INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Haha, it actually does implement it... I simplified sooo much the code that I forgot to add this :) let me correct it

Comment: and why not having IFoo and their friends inherit from a List rather than having a List in a value property ?

Comment: Because, again this is the "Incredibly simplified version which only shows the problem core", I don't really want to post the 784 lines of code that rally contains the class :)